# Function not creating object for database correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im working on an assignment to make a mock banking app, when I use the direct routing (localhost:3000/account/create/:name/:email:/password) the object gets added correctly to my database, like this

{"_id":"634862510589b498ff27dc13","name":"harris","email":"harris@gmail.com","password":"secret","balance":0},

but when I try to put the info into a card directly it comes out as

{"_id":"63486d430589b498ff27dc16","name":"${name}","email":"${email}","password":"${password}","balance":0},

I do get an error saying Im running on react 17, but im not sure what I would need to change. Any help would be greatly apprecated

```
function CreateAccount(){
  const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);
  const [show, setShow]     = React.useState(true);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <Card
      bgcolor="primary"
      header="Create Account"
      status={status}
      body={show ? 
        <CreateForm setShow={setShow}/> : 
        <CreateMsg setShow={setShow}/>}
    />
  )
}

function CreateMsg(props){
  return(<>
    <h5>New Account Sucessfully Created!</h5>
    <button type="submit" 
      className="btn btn-light" 
      onClick={() => props.setShow(true)}>Add another account</button>
  </>);
}

function CreateForm(props){
  const [name, setName]         = React.useState('');
  const [email, setEmail]       = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
   

  function handle(){
    console.log(name,email,password);
    const url = 'account/create/${name}/${email}/${password}';
    (async () => {
      var res = await fetch(url);
      var data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    })();
    props.setShow(false);
  }    

  return (<>

    Name<br/>
    <input type="input" 
      className="form-control" 
      placeholder="Enter name" 
      value={name} 
      onChange={e => setName(e.currentTarget.value)} /><br/>

    Email address<br/>
    <input type="input" 
      className="form-control" 
      placeholder="Enter email" 
      value={email} 
      onChange={e => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}/><br/>

    Password<br/>
    <input type="password" 
      className="form-control" 
      placeholder="Enter password" 
      value={password} 
      onChange={e => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)}/><br/>

    <button type="submit" 
      className="btn btn-light" 
      onClick={handle}>Create Account</button>

  </>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a issue with using regular quotation marks versus backticks. Regular single quotes for a string just make all the text inside them a string. Backticks: `` can insert variables into a string. Variables that you denote inside curly brackets that start with a dollar sign: `${variable}`.

So in short, your line: `const url = 'account/create/${name}/${email}/${password}';` the string should be using backticks instead of regular quotes. Like so:

```
const url = `account/create/${name}/${email}/${password}`;
```

That way the name, email, and password variables will get interpolated into the string and read correctly.